# Saving and removing things from Pocket

Tags: pocket

I have a lot of things stored in my Pocket on my computer.  I do not want to lose them, but I want to clean out my pocket.  How can I save them and then delete and empty the "Pocket"?

Answer (score 0):

Pocket has an [export process](https://getpocket.com/export) that you can make use of. The export is an HTML file of your bookmarks.